# Having trouble piping output of dscl -list to -dscl read using xargs

Tags: macos, pipe, xargs

I'm trying to get every user using `dscl` and reading each of their records using `xargs` and `dscl`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, though, because I would expect this command to take each line of output and place it where `{}` is.

```
2rs2ts:~/ $ dscl . -list /Users | xargs -n1I'{}' dscl -plist . -read /Users/{}
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)
... and so forth
```

The output of the first command seems just fine...

```
2rs2ts:~/ $ dscl . -list /Users
2rs2ts
_amavisd
_appleevents
... and so forth
```

I even pipe that to `xargs -n1 echo` and it seems fine. I `echo` something else first and it works as expected. I've also tried using `-L1` instead, but to no avail. What am I missing?

I *am* aware I can use `-readall` for this, but, I was just trying to use `xargs` for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `-n1I'{}'`. You want to split those two options, otherwise `xargs` can't parse them correctly. Basically, after each option-argument (`1` and `'{}'` in your case), you need a whitespace separator:

```
dscl . -list /Users | xargs -n1 -I'{}' dscl -plist . -read /Users/{}
```

---

Or, if you just want to use a simple loop:

```
for user in $(dscl . -list /Users); do dscl -plist . -read /Users/"$user"; done
```

With `while read`, you can use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
while read user; do dscl -plist . -read /Users/"$user"; done < <(dscl . -list /Users)
```

… or you pipe it:

```
dscl . -list /Users | while read user; do dscl -plist . -read /Users/"$user"; done
```

Comment: Weird. I guess in all the combinations I tried I never did the right thing, and I must have excluded possibilities because I thought they'd be redundant. Thanks! By the way, your second answer also works and it's very similar to [this answer on Unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7561/40890) but it actually works whereas that one did not.

Comment: The `<` only works for files. If you want it to use arbitrary input from a command, you need process substitution (see my updated answer).

Comment: That user gave an example with a pipe, though. I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, I only looked at the second example. First one works as well, I appended it to my answer.

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong without noticing it earlier, because that pipe example (except for calling it `line` instead as per the linked example) didn't work for me before! Thank you nonetheless.